# debian wheezy - how to mount unused disks?

Tags: linux, debian, mount

I'm mostly a database guy but i have debian wheezy server with 4 hard disks.  It was set up using one disk a while back, that one was all that was needed.  Now, i need more space and the thing, i think, that is throwing me off is the UUID disk stuff.

anyway:

```
/mnt# lsblk -io KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL
KNAME TYPE   SIZE MODEL
sdb   disk 232.9G Hitachi HDP72502
sdc   disk 232.9G Hitachi HDP72502
sda   disk 232.9G Hitachi HDP72502
sda1  part 223.4G
sda2  part     1K
sda5  part   9.5G
sdd   disk 232.9G Hitachi HDP72502
sr0   rom   1024M DVD A  DS8A1P
```

Root is mounted to sda.  sdb, c and d are unused, unformatted etc.  i just need some more space, so i have created /mnt/ext_b/ and so on for b, c, d.

mount shows:

/dev/disk/by-uuid/1b1e97e4-3c04-4e50-8e06-b16752778717 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)

which is correct.  i want to mount the others just for space, how do i get their UUIDs?

```
/mnt# blkid
/dev/sda5: UUID="f70ad0b2-a9d0-430a-829c-d2e37245fd71" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda1: UUID="1b1e97e4-3c04-4e50-8e06-b16752778717" TYPE="ext4"
```

how do i get the UUIDs to put formatted filesystems on the disks?

```
/mnt# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
mke2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Could not stat /dev/sdb1 --- No such file or directory
```

thanks in advance.

matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that those additional disks haven't been touched since they were connected to the server and don't have even partitions yet. In general, adding extra disk space in Linux can be done in the following steps:

1. Attach new disk to the server
2. Create partition table on it
3. Add one or more partitions to the disk
4. Format partition to the FS of your choice
5. Mounting this partition to the mount point of your choice
6. Make those mount persistent by adding appropriate line to the `/etc/fstab`

If you have multiple disks you may consider to create hardware RAID disk if you have RAID controller or software RAID, using [mdadm tool](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup). Both ways you'll get larger single disk(size would depend from the RAID level you choose) for which you'll need to go to step 2 and farther. It's worth mentioning that there is another way to get larger than single disk usable space from multiple disks called Logical Volume Manager or [LVM](https://wiki.debian.org/LVM). It's more sophisticated than MDM and allows to create FS snapshots and add extra disk space to the volume without need to create additional mountpoints.

Whatever you choose you'll need to create a partition table on a new disk/LVM volume/MDM disk. Here you need to make another choice - what type of partition table to use, `MBR` or `GPT`. Check [Partitioning HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/) for more details, but in general I'd recommend GPT for large non-bootable disks.

Same HOWTO will tell you, how create partition(s) on the selected disk. At this point you'll get devices like `/dev/sdb1`, etc.

Then you can go to step 4, the one you already tried:

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

That should succeed now and you'll be able to get UUID of a new FS with `blkid`. Add obtained UUID to your `/etc/fstab` file and mount newly created FS to it's mount point.

Comment: thank you Timur for your answer, it is very helpful.

Comment: are you saying i could have, for example, one logical disk of 750G rather than 3x250?  if so, i would be very interested in doing that even if it's more difficult.  this box normally gets data files and we have had a small number in excess of the 250G limit, so being able to handle those would be a benefit, previously we moved them to a different box.  i don't know much about RAID, and critical redundancy is not necessary for this box, everything important is stored elsewhere.  to have the extra space, beyond 3x250G would be very useful. i will look into the mdadm tool you indicated, and LVM

Comment: at the debian wiki for LVM i was able to set up an LVM.  i now have available disk space of 650G - far better than what i was attempting to do!  thank you everyone for your help!!

Comment: Glad it helped! LVM is very powerful concept, but it has it's own drawbacks, most notable is some performance degradation, compared to the raw disks. Also, be aware, that by just concatenating your disks into one large volume you significantly increase the risk of losing *ALL* data placed on that volume by the number of involved disks(3 times). Basically you get RAID0 with all it's benefits and drawbacks. See [RAID levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels) and [RAID Explained with Diagrams](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial/)

Comment: [This tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_RAID_and_LVM) although for Arch Linux can give you nice walk through if you'd like to combine MDM and LVM together. There is also an option to add data redundancy to LVM with `lvcreate` parameters like `--mirrors 1` and/or `--type raid1|raid5`. See http://serverfault.com/questions/595045/redundancy-lvmmdadm-or-lvm-internal-raid
And, as a general rule - *ALWAYS* do backups!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you must create partitions on disks. 
Think about storing your data. You have similar disks. It must be raid? If it must be raid, what type of raid it must be?

You can create partition with `fdisk` or some alternatives (`gparted`, `cfdisk` and so on).
There are a lot information in internet and manuals.

May be you need LVM? Some people say that it may slow down your database, but it gives you opportunity to get snapshots.

After creating partitions you can create filesystem and can mount it.
Usually people recommend to use XFS or Ext4 for databases.

And don't forget to set right mount flags to your filestystem.
`noatime`,`nodiratime` and `barrier=0` will improve performance, but with `barrier=0` in some cases you can loose your data. In case of Ext4 look at `data` (may be in your case you can set it in `ordered`).

**UPD:** may be this question must be in superuser or unix section?

Answer (score 0):

You supposed to create [partition](https://wiki.debian.org/Partition) with utility like the fdisk, cfdisk, gparted or [partitionmanager](https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/admin/partitionmanager) before you can format it.